# getting a notification when printing is completed

Tags: java, printing

I use `java.awt.print` and `javax.print` to enable printing in our applications. Is it possible to get a notification when printing is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is to use a `PrintJobListener`. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687184/java-check-if-file-is-in-print-queue-in-use/3690164#3690164) for more information and an example.

Comment: You can also extend PrintJobAdapter and override

public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje)  {

    }