# File names from print queue java

Tags: java, printing, java-print

How can I get the file names in the print queue from Java?
I would like to get all items in the print queue, even those not started through the `PrintJob` API.

I know that I can use the `PrintService#getAttributes` method to get all Attributes and then check the "queued-job-count" attribute for how many items are in the print queue as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367276/2084190) question.
Is it possible to get the names of the files in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to filter attributes by JobName class
`(package javax.print.attribute.standard)`.