# How can I know when a javax.jnlp.PrintService is done printing my Printable object

Tags: java, printing, jnlp

I'm using JNLP to print some images inside an applet.  I pass a `Printable` object to a `javax.jnlp.PrintService` instance and call `PrintService.print()`.  Is there any way to know when this operation completes?

Looking at line 116 of [the PrintService source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/jnlp/PrintServiceImpl.java.html), it seems to start a thread for printing and not attach anything to keep track of it.

There seems to be mechanisms for [tracking print operations](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/print/determine-that-print-job-has-finished) in other parts of Java, but I have not had success using other printing mechanisms in the context of a browser applet. (the user is constantly nagged about security)

Is it possible to print something in a signed java applet, not have the user be nagged about security, and know when the print operation finishes?

Comment: *" not have the user be nagged about security"*  If 'asking once' is 'not being nagged', digitally sign the applet, get the user to accept it once at start-up, then print using the usual print services.

Comment: @Andrew That is what I do currently, however I'm restricted to JNLP print services, no?

Comment: I left that for a while to see if I could make sense of it.  I cannot.  If an applet is trusted, it can use the [AWT printing API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/package-frame.html), if is deployed uning JNLP and sand-boxed, it needs to use the `javax.jnlp.PrintService` for printing.  Which is used in the code?

Comment: @AndrewThompson We use JNLP for deploying the applet.

Comment: And the answer to my question would be, what?  The code is using AWT or the `PrintService`?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I eventually got to the bottom of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by switching from using `javax.jnlp.PrintService` to using `javax.print.PrintService`.  Using the later allows you to attach a PrintJobAdapter to monitor the status of the print job.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687184/java-check-if-file-is-in-print-queue-in-use) Stack Overflow question.

All of this is perfectly acceptable in a JNLP deployed applet, provided the applet is signed.