# Java, printing file using its path on disk

Tags: java, printing, filepath

Is it possible to print a file (txt, image, pdf, ...) to a printer using its path?

For example:

I have a file in `C:\directory\file.txt`. Can I give this path to java and launch a print command to printer?

Comment: By printing, I suppose you mean to a printer?

Comment: @fge yes I mean printer

Comment: Oh, an actual printer. I thought you were talking about the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687184/java-check-if-file-is-in-print-queue-in-use <- Look at the accepted answer here.

Comment: You'll have to be able to read the file first. Either by implementing that functionality yourself (a bad idea in most cases) or by using someone elses implementation.

Comment: the file that I want to print can be a txt, pdf or image.So I need a way to print it without reading it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting and printing to a printer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278405/connecting-and-printing-to-a-printer-in-java)

Comment: Very basic answer - yes you can.  You really need to show that you've had a go at this and any code samples you've tried / problems you've had.  Have a look at the questions linked in comments above - basically all pointing you to the javax.print package. Tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/, API docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/package-frame.html

Answer (score 1):

try this
`String file_path = "C:\directory\file.txt"`
`Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(file_path));`